# For any countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is some closed set of reals whose Cantor-Bendixson rank is $\alpha$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, ordinals, descriptive-set-theory

I want to prove that for any countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is some closed set $C\subset \mathbb R$ such that the Cantor-Bendixson rank of $C$ is $\alpha$.

I have not been able to create a successful construction and am out of ideas right now, but I still believe this should be true. Could anybody give a proof (or counterexample)?

Comment: Does it work?: Recursively take $C_1 = \{0\}\cup \{1/n : n<\omega\}$ and take $C_{\alpha+1}$ as replacing all isolated points of $C_\alpha$ to a sufficiently small copy of $C_1$. For limit $\delta$, take $C_\delta$ the union of all $C_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\delta$.

Comment: @HanulJeon I think that may work. But I don't see how to work out the details. Could you expand please?

Comment: I realize that my construction does not guarantee $C_\omega$ is a closed set.

Comment: Related: [Embedding ordinals in $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123969/embedding-ordinals-in-mathbbq) AND [Countable ordinals are embeddable in the rationals $\Bbb Q$ -- proofs and their use of AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408300/countable-ordinals-are-embeddable-in-the-rationals-bbb-q-proofs-and-their) AND [A canonical injection $f:\alpha\to[0,1]$ for an arbitrary countable ordinal $\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714125/a-canonical-injection-f-alpha-to0-1-for-an-arbitrary-countable-ordinal-al).

Comment: Cantor-Bendix**s**on

Comment: [Similar question without the closed assumption in $C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761268/is-there-a-subset-of-r-such-that-its-cantor-bendixson-rank-is-the-first-limit-or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a countable ordinal $\alpha$, consider the (compact) space $X_\alpha = \omega^\alpha+1$ (ordinal exponentiation of course, so this is a countable ordinal) in the order topology. It's classical that the Cantor Bendixson rank of $X_\alpha$ is exactly $\alpha$. You could probably show it by transfinite induction. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1104/1104.0287v1.pdf) has more details.

And every countable ordinal in the order topology is metrisable (second countable and normal) and embeds into $\mathbb{Q}$ (which contains an order isomorphic copy of any countable ordered space) and thus into the the reals.

[This question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37151/4280) give more info again.

Comment: The rank is $\alpha+1$, not $\alpha$.